# Calculate roots of polynomial in MySQL

Tags: mysql, numpy, polynomials, mysql-8.0, eigenvalue

I current use the numpy `roots` function as follows:

```
y = numpy.roots([-2, 3, 0, -1 * x])[1]
```

In the above `x` is a column in a table that I extract to run through the function.

If possible I'd like to move this into a MySQL query. I've tried replicating the nuts and bolts of the function but quickly got lost when I got to eigenvalues.

I'm not even close to being a mathmatician so I'm wondering if anyone here has attempted this?

Comment: Why the [tag:eigenvalue] tag and what do you mean when you say you want to move it into a MySQL query?

Comment: Are you familiar with MySQL's [stored functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines.html)? You may be able to write your code in that clunky and difficult-to-debug language. One helpful thing: numbers in that langiage are all double-precision floating point. It has to be said, though, that in many applications the dbms is a bottleneck and it's therefore unwise to cram lots of number-crunching into it when you can do that work in your python code.

Comment: @jared - the eigenvalue tag is because the roots package makes use of eigenvalues. On the SQL query - I currently extract data from a MySQL table and use python to calculate `y`. I'm wondering if this could be done using an SQL query.

Comment: @Jossy you cannot do this via a query. You need to write a stored procedure or a compiled function. However, it is extremely unlikely that anybody will write this for you from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL is primarily designed for database operations, calculating the roots of a polynomial directly in a MySQL query does not seem very practical. Although, by using a SLF(Server Loadable Function) this should allow you to write a custom function in a another language like C or C++, then integrate said function into MySQL.

Read more about SLF
[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-loadable-functions.html)
Or
[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/5.7/en/adding-loadable-function.html)

Answer (score 1):

For polynomials of small order, you might be able to do it simply by using the general solution formulas. Order 1 is trivial, order two uses the good old quadratic formula we were all taught at school. Your example appears to be cubic polynomial. There is a general formula for the roots of

```
ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0
```

given by (courtesy of Wikipedia)

[image: cube root formula part1/3]

[image: cube root formula part2/3]

[image: cube root formula part3/3]

There are 1 to 3 real roots of a general cubic polynomial. The formula above can generate all roots (real and complex) if you multiply C by the cube roots of unity 1, (sqrt(-3) - 1)/2, (-sqrt(-3) - 1)/2. Mysql doesn't support complex numbers so you'll have to expand it all out. I concur with gitg0 that this isn't a very practical way to approach this problem, but it looks doable with some work.